# unity NavMeshAgent не выпекает ничего

Tags: c#, unity3d

Создал врага, накинул на него NavMeshAgent, зашел во вкладку Navigation, нажимаю на Bake но, ничего не происходит. Все возможное перепробовал, не помогает, кода нет.

Comment: `Все возможное` - значит то что вы хотите, невозможно, ну или не всё.

Comment: @aepot почти все возможное, не пробовал только решение, так как не знаю его